# Let $G$ be a group with $|G| = 18$. Suppose that $G$ has a cyclic subgroup of order $9$. Classify $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

I know the answer to this question but I still don't understand how to find it and why it is only $Z_{18}$ and $D_{18}$. Can someone please explain it and try to be as clear as possible?

Comment: It must be a semi-direct product.

Comment: can explain what you mean?

Answer (score 3):

Let $H$ be the cyclic subgroup of order 9. Then $H$ is normal in $G$. Let $h$ be a generator of $H$. Let $i \in G$ be an element of order 2 (which must exist). Then $ihi^{-1} = h^n$ for some $n$.

Then $h = i^2hi^{-2} = i(ihi^{-1})i^{-1} = ih^ni^{-1} = h^{n^2}$. So $n = \pm 1$. If $n = 1$ then the group is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_{18}$, and if $n = -1$ then the group is isomorphic to $D_{18}$.

Comment: This only means that $h^{n^2-1}=1$, that is, $\operatorname{ord}(h)=9$ divides $n^2-1$, not that $n^2-1=0$.

Comment: So $9 | (n^2 - 1)$, and $n \equiv \pm 1 \pmod 9$... But $h^9 = id_G$.

Comment: Sure :) I mean that this step may be not quite clear and deserves including in the answer.

Comment: Yeah, there are details missing here and there. Since I am not yet sure this question is from a homework or something else, just let me make it in the form of a hint.

Comment: I think I'm starting to get it. if h is commutes, then its Z18 and if it doesn't it's D18? oh and it's for a project. I was told to research and ask for help.

Comment: That is right. To confirm, you can try to write down an isomorphism by mapping $i$ and $h$ to suitable elements in $\mathbb Z_{18}$ or $D_{18}$.

Comment: Thank you! I was having trouble with this and my professor said I'm not allowed to use any theorems and that got me stuck.

Answer (score 3):

Let $Z \leq G$ be the cyclic subgroup of order $9$.  Since $|G:Z| = 2$, $Z$ is normal in $G$ and $G/Z \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.  This $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ acts on $Z$ by conjugation, producing automorphisms of $Z$, $\mathrm{Aut}(Z) \cong Z^\times$, and such automorphisms are specified by their image of $1$ since $Z$ is cyclic.  If the action is the identity, we get $$G \cong Z \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}/18\mathbb{Z} \cong \langle 1_Z, 1_2 \mid 1_2 1_Z 1_2^{-1} = 1_Z \rangle  \text{.}$$  If the action is inversion, $\varphi_1(z) = z^{-1}$, $$G \cong Z \rtimes_\varphi \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \cong D_{18} \cong \langle 1_Z, 1_2 \mid 1_2 1_Z 1_2^{-1} = 1_Z^{-1} \rangle  \text{.}$$  As no other subgroup of $\mathrm{Aut}(Z) \cong Z^\times$ has order divisible by $2$, there are no other actions to consider.